# I need to create a macro that colors cells a specific color if it falls within a range or numbers

Tags: css, vba, excel, colors

I need a macro that colors cells in a specific column a specific color depending on the range.

In Column A: If it falls under 95, it colors it red
If it is 95>= cell <98.5 then it colors yellow
If it is >=98.5 then it colors it custom green (0, 255, 0)

In Column B: If it falls 98 then it is red. between 98 & 99 is yellow  and > 99 is Green (0, 255,0)

In Column C: If it is less than 1 then it is Green (0,255,0), if it is (1 =< cell <2) yellow, If cell >= 2 then  it is red.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you attempted and failed to get working?  StackOverflow is not set up to just ask people for code snippets.  Make an attempt to get a macro to work and then come back with specific issues with your implementation and you will be more likely to get help.

Comment: Why do you need a macro for this? Could you not just use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

DEVELOPER > Code - Record Macro, OK, select ColumnA, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  less than  `=95`  Format…, red, OK, OK

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  between  `=95` and `=98.5`, Format…, yellow, OK, OK

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  between  `=98.5` and `=1E+100`, Format…, green, OK, OK

Select ColumnB, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Values  less than `=98`, Format…, red, OK, OK

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  between  `=98` and `=99`, Format…, yellow, OK, OK

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  greater than or equal to  `=99`, Format…, green, OK, OK

Select ColumnC, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  less than  `=1`, Format…, green, OK, OK

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  between  `=1` and `=2`, Format…, yellow, OK, OK

HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule…, *Format only cells that contain*, **Format only cells with:**

Cell Value  greater than or equal to `=2`, Format…, red, OK, OK, DEVELOPER > Code – Stop Recording.